# Pointer may not point to null objects java openCL

Tags: java, pointers, opencl, jocl

I am using a kernel that has an image as a parameter with java and JOCL

```
input ="12.jpg";
image = createBufferedImage(input);
image = createBufferedImage(input);
DataBufferInt dataBufferSrc = (DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
int dataSrc[] = dataBufferSrc.getData();
inputImageMem = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY| CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR,
            dataSrc.length * Sizeof.cl_uint, Pointer.to(dataSrc), null);
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(inputImageMem));
```

When I compile, I get the error:

> Pointer may not point to null objects

It is in the line:

```
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(inputImageMem));
```

What is the probable problem? How can I fix it?

PS: `createBufferedImage` is a function taken from JOCL samples
http://jocl.org/

Answer (score 1):

From the openCL clCreateBuffer [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateBuffer.html):

> Returns a valid non-zero buffer object and errcode_ret is set to CL_SUCCESS if the buffer object is created successfully. **Otherwise, it returns a NULL value** with one of the following error values returned in errcode_ret...

The last parameter of `clCreateBuffer` function is an int pointer (where you want the error code to be returned). You currently have it set to `null`. My guess is that something failed in `clCreateBuffer`. I'd recommend checking the value of `errcode_ret`, it will contain an error code that will help you fix the issue.

Comment: In the documentation, they said that when the the value of the buffer is null it returns to NULL with one of the following error values returned in errcode_ret: **CL_INVALID_CONTEXT** or **CL_INVALID_VALUE** or **CL_INVALID_BUFFER_SIZE** or **CL_INVALID_HOST_PTR** or .....but in my code There is just : 'Pointer may not point to null objects'       Is there any way to see the errors?

Comment: @NasimaInfo You need to do it yourself: pass a pointer to contain the error value as the last argument of `clCreateBuffer`. I'm not entirely sure how it works in java. Pointers are C/C++ thing and java should not even use them. JOCL Pointer class seems to be some sort of a weird hack around it. Maybe create a pointer object to an integer, pass it as a last argument of `clCreateBuffer` and check if it equals any error codes somehow...? I'm not really a java expert or a pointer expert.

Comment: 'Pointer may not point to null objects' logical, since you are calling to Pointer.to(). And Pointer is what gives you the error. But the source is in clCreateBuffer()

Comment: @Kilves Yes, the pointer class is an attempt to emulate a C `void*` pointer. It's not uncommon for JNI bindings of libraries like CL,GL and others, which *heavily* make use of `void*` pointers.

Comment: Regarding the error: The message "Pointer may not point to null objects" is part of an `IllegalArgumentException` that is thrown when the argument to `Pointer.to(...)` is `null`. In this case, the `inputImageMem` is `null`. Usually, the `clCreatebuffer` call should not return `null`, unless there was an error. And if you have set `CL.setExceptionsEnabled(true)`, for example, at the beginning of your `main` method, then it should print messages when errors occur, even if you do *not* manually check the error code. An *compilable* example that shows what exacty you are doing would be helpful.